# How to Compute initial state of checkbox and subsribe to later state changes in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I want to check/uncheck a checkbox in the initial pageload based on a computed value. Later when the user checks/unchecks the checkbox I want to capture that.

```html
 <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 pull-right">
        <input type="checkbox" class="control-label" data-bind="checked:IsGroup" />
        <label class="control-label form-label" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">Medical Group</label>
    </div>
```

```javascript
self.IsGroup = ko.computed(function () {
        return someValue == null ? false : true;
    });

self.IsGroup .subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) {

            alert(newValue);
        }
        else {
            alert(newValue);
        }
    });
```

The subscribe event is not firing. How to approach this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *read only* computed. Make it writable like so:

```
self.IsGroup = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return someValue == null ? false : true;
    },
    write: function(newValue) {
        someValue = newValue;
        alert(newValue);
    }
});
```

Note that this actually means you don't *need* a subscription: you can fire your custom logic (e.g. the `alert`) right there in the `write` function. This is exactly what *writeable* computeds are good for.

For further details refer to [the official `computed` documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

Comment: The write function is firing only for new value, in this case if the checkbox is checked on load and if I uncheck then writable function is firing, but when I check again then its not firing.Is there a way to do that?